# Test whether a UIView is hidden using XCUITest

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, hidden, xcode-ui-testing

How do I test whether a view is hidden using XCUITest?  A view is sometimes hidden (set in Xcode like this: [Hidden view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eeE0.png))
How do I test for that in XCUITest using Swift?  In my case, the view is just a label.  I tried something like this: `XCTAssertFalse(app.staticTexts["pushNotificationInstruction"].accessibilityElementsHidden)` .  But that's not it.  accessibilityElementsHidden is not the same as the view is hidden.  Thanks.

Comment: btw, you can use `XCTAssertTrue` and `XCTAssertFalse` for checking booleans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible using XCUITest. Here is a developer forum thread where an Apple engineer suggested filing a radar for this exact issue:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46271

I have personally filed a couple radars relating to the limitations imposed by not being able to access certain properties of UIViews from within an XCUITest. I encourage you to do the same and provide details of the scenarios you are blocked from testing because of this deficiency in XCUITest.

Comment: perhaps you can give EarlGrey a try: http://www.github.com/google/EarlGrey?

Answer (score 0):

You can assert that the view does not exists and use another test to check the scenario when it does exists. Maybe a bit fragile, but that would cover you case.

```
let viewControllerShown = app.otherElements["view_myviewcontroller"].waitForExistence(timeout: 5)
XCTAssert(viewControllerShown)
let instructionViewExists = app.staticTexts["pushNotificationInstruction"].exists
XCTAssertFalse(instructionViewExists)
```

Answer (score 0):

An expedient solution is to carry the visibility state of the view in its [accessibilityidentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsaccessibility/1535023-accessibilityidentifier).

In your view controller:

```
view.isHidden = hideView
view.accessibilityidentifier = "view1"+(hideView ? "hidden" : "")
```

In your tests:

```
XCTAssert(app.otherElements["view1"].exists)
```

or

```
XCTAssertFalse(app.otherElements["view1"].exists)
```

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the documentation of `exist`:

> The fact that an element exists does not imply that it is hittable.
>   Elements can exist offscreen, or exist onscreen but be hidden by
>   another element, causing their isHittable property to return false.

It means that you can check:

```
if uiElement.exists && uiElement.isHittable {
    XCTFail()
}
```

Comment: Did you test it, does this mean that a hidden elemenent is not hittable?